# mongodb findOne does not return what I expect

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

When I check my Database in the Google Chrome Console with `MachineReady.findOne({_id:"BYNbKqncKHmgfFK2q"}, {machineId:1, _id:0});`
it returns the whole Document and not just the machineId.
When I run the same Command in a mongo shell, it works great.

What am I missing? Is this because I run this in the Client side (all documents are loaded already)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a. It should be `MachineReady.findOne({_id:"BYNbKqncKHmgfFK2q"}, {fields:{_id:1}})`

b. Currently you cannot exclude and include fields in the same query so `{machineId:1, _id:0}` won't work.

Comment: Note also that the `_id` field is always included in addition to whatever other fields are requested. I haven't tried *excluding* the `_id` field though.

Comment: Thanks, I was under the impression all features in the mongo doc are working as shown also in java script files.

Answer (score 0):

Google chrome console you have to include `.fetch()` at the end.

```
MachineReady.findOne({_id:"BYNbKqncKHmgfFK2q"}, {machineId:1, _id:0}).fetch();
```